# Create table in derby with primary key auto increment

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, derby

I am having some trouble trying to figure out how to create tables java DB where the primary keys will auto increment. Below is my code:

```
   --DROP Table Customer;
CREATE TABLE Customer (
  Name varchar(20),
  Address varchar(60),
  id INT not null primary key GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
);


INSERT INTO Customer (Name, Address, id) VALUES
('Eva Smith', '129 Station Rd, London, N3 2AS', 1),
('Rob Manton', '23 Bow Lane, London, N3', 2),
('Bob Currie', '54 Teignmouth Rd, London, NW2', 3),
('Jim Hunter', '765 High Road, London, N12', 4),
('Phil Johnson', '75 Squires Lane, London, N3', 5),
('Saim Soyler', '2 Rosemary Ave, London, N3', 6),
('Gul Hikmet', '31 Clifton Rd, London, N3 2SG', 7);
```

However, this code gives me the error:

```
[Exception, Error code 30,000, SQLState 42X01] Syntax error: Encountered ")" at line 5, column 1.
Line 6, column 1
```

I've searched around to find solutions to this however, although there are a lot of topics posted about this I cannot find a fix that works. I have also tried to manually include the column 'ID' as shown in the picture below but this also does not work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVBpM.png)

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I am using Netbeans version 8.2.

Comment: You have a trailing comma after `INCREMENT BY 1`, but you should tell what your target database is, as your syntax is probably database dependent.

Comment: Hey so the target database is: "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Alphacab [root on ROOT]"

Comment: Thanks to your response I was able to workout how to fix the issue, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Seano989 Please post your solution as an answer to be accepted so this Question will be considered closed.